# Validation of select element on the page

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

how to write validation for select tag ?
this is my code for select tag,but i am not getting validation for select ,message also not came.

html code

```
<form>
 <ion-list [ngFormModel]="registrationForm">
<ion-item>
      <ion-label floating>Preffer Payment<span class="redtxt">*</span></ion-label>
        <ion-select ngControl="pay">
          <ion-option>Neft/Rtgs/Imps</ion-option>
          <ion-option>Debet/Credit</ion-option>
          <ion-option>Net Banking</ion-option>
        </ion-select>
      <div control="pay" class="validation-error">This is required</div>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
<form>
```

ts code

```
public registrationForm:any;
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public _form: FormBuilder) {
this.registrationForm = this._form.group({
            "pay":["",Validators.required]
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `controls` array of you `registrationForm` to show a message if that property is not valid.

```
<form>
  <ion-list [ngFormModel]="registrationForm">

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating>Preffer Payment<span class="redtxt">*</span></ion-label>
        <ion-select ngControl="pay">
          <ion-option>Neft/Rtgs/Imps</ion-option>
          <ion-option>Debet/Credit</ion-option>
          <ion-option>Net Banking</ion-option>
        </ion-select>     
    </ion-item>

    <!-- Error message -->
    <ion-item *ngIf="!registrationForm.controls.pay.valid">
      <div control="pay" class="validation-error">This is required</div>
    </ion-item>

  </ion-list>
<form>
```